# dropdown dont show correct(parent div has overflow auto)

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, overflow

i am working on a project, this site has flexible values to fit any resolution. The issue is that in one of my divs there's an dropdown menu, but it doesn't shows correct(being cutoff) because the parent div has an overflow auto it cutoff the part thats outside the div.

The div needs the overflow auto because it has a border and a padding

basic code

```
div.box{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px;
}
.dd-btn{
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.dd-btn ul{
    list-style:none;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:22px;
    right:0;
    z-index:100;
    background:#000 
}
.dd-btn ul li{
    width:100px;
    float:left; 
}


<div class="box">
   <ul>
       <li>link</li>
       <li>link</li>
       <li>link</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

this div cant have a float or width:100% or a height because of the structure of the whole site. Content and resolution will change.

Is there a simple trick for this issue?

Found a solution:

```
.box:after{
    clear:both;
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    height:0;
    line-height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
}
```

using this i can get rid of the overflow auto and the box will be display correct

Comment: you can try adjusting its z-index value

Comment: already tried that...no effect

Comment: is it necessary at all using overflow:auto?

Comment: sadly yes, if you dont give an parent div an float and width it will cutoff the elements thats inside.

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu_list {
  ...
  overflow: visible;
}
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: please post some more code... and check which css rules are being applied to the menu by using the inspect element feature in your browser. There is no mystery here. The tool will tell you exactly which css rules have been applied to your item of interest.